# Ask for iOS 8 device APNS token twice

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push, token

So I already have called

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotifications]
```

and successfully got apns token through

```
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
```

delegate method but I did nothing with it and iOS do not allow me to ask user for push notification access again.

How can I get device APNS token after user already accepted to receive notification?

Comment: do you want the alert message to be appeared again or do you want APN token again?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **remove application** then **set time for one or two days in the future** and then **restart your iPhone**. It should work after.

Changing Bundle Identifier will also make application ask for notifications permission but is kinda uglier than first sollution

Answer (score 0):

Once you have asked for the push notification from the user, You can save it in NSUserDefaults or on your server for future use. I think storing of device token on server will be a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you aplly for DeviceToken,
then you can get the token.

such as:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotifications] ;

then the delegate method
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
 would receive the token as same as the first time.

wish to be help to you.  :)